# Recurrence relations with ternary series

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I need to find the amount of ternary series (0,1,2) in the length of n that an appearance of at least one 0 between every two appearances of 2.

I marked the amount as $a_n$ and with simple logic I got to $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + $the amount of series that with the length of n-1 that if you add to them 2 in the end they will be legit. But I can't find this amount.

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain the simple logic. That, I feel, is more important than the solution itself. I can explain the solution once you do this.

Comment: If you add to a legit series with the length of n-1 at the end 0 or 1 then the series stay legit. So you can get to $2a_{n-1}$. Then what's left is if you add to a legit series 2 at the end. Here it's surely less than $a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Okay, I will try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem we get from first principles the generating function

$$G(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} g_n z^n =
\frac{1}{1-2z} + \frac{1}{1-2z} z \frac{1}{1-2z}\\ +
\frac{1}{1-2z} z \times
\left(
\sum_{q\ge 1} ((2^1-1)z + (2^2-1)z^2 + (2^3-1)z^3+\cdots)^q z^q
\right)  \times
\frac{1}{1-2z}.$$

The first  term counts  strings where  no two  appears and  the second
where   it    appears   once.   The    third   has   at    least   two
appearances. Simplify to get

$$G(z) = \frac{1}{1-2z} + \frac{z}{(1-2z)^2}
+ \frac{z}{(1-2z)^2}
\sum_{q\ge 1} \left(\frac{2z}{1-2z} - \frac{z}{1-z}\right)^q z^q
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z} + \frac{z}{(1-2z)^2}
+ \frac{z}{(1-2z)^2}
\sum_{q\ge 1} \left(\frac{z}{(1-z)(1-2z)}\right)^q z^q
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z} 
+ \frac{z}{(1-2z)^2}
\sum_{q\ge 0} \left(\frac{z}{(1-z)(1-2z)}\right)^q z^q
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z} 
+ \frac{z}{(1-2z)^2} \frac{1}{1-z^2/(1-z)/(1-2z)}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z} 
+ \frac{z}{1-2z} \frac{1}{1-2z-z^2/(1-z)}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z} 
+ \frac{1}{1-2z} \frac{z(1-z)}{1-2z-z+2z^2-z^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z} 
+ \frac{1}{1-2z} \frac{z(1-z)}{1-3z+z^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-2z} \frac{1-2z}{1-3z+z^2}
= \frac{1}{1-3z+z^2}.$$

Now to turn this into a recurrence we start from

$$G(z) (1-3z+z^2) = 1$$

and extract the coefficient on $[z^n]$ where $n\ge 2$ to get

$$ [z^n] G(z) (1-3z+z^2) =
g_n - 3 g_{n-1} + g_{n-2} = 0$$

or

$$g_n = 3 g_{n-1} - g_{n-2}.$$

Recall that for Fibonacci numbers

$$F_{2n} = F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-2}
= 2 F_{2n-2} + F_{2n-3}
= 3 F_{2n-2} - F_{2n-4}$$

and

$$F_{2n+1} = F_{2n} + F_{2n-1}
= 2 F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-2}
= 3 F_{2n-1} - F_{2n-3}.$$

Therefore $G(z)$ enumerates a type of Fibonacci number. To determine which
we observe that

$$G(z) = \sum_{p\ge 0} z^p (3-z)^p$$

so that $g_0 = 1 = F_2$ and $g_1 = 3 = F_4$

and we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{ F_{2n+2}.}$$

Here is some Maple code to document the problem definition that was used.

```
with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx, d, res, p1, p2, zero, p;

    res := 0;

    for idx from 3^n to 2*3^n-1 do
        d := convert(idx, base, 3);

        for p1 to n do
            if d[p1] = 2 then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        for p2 from n to 1 by -1 do
            if d[p2] = 2 then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if p2 <= p1 then
            res := res + 1;
        else
            zero := 0;
            for p from p1+1 to p2 do
                if d[p] = 2 then
                    if zero = 0 then
                        break;
                    else
                        zero := 0;
                    fi;
                elif d[p] = 0 then
                    zero := zero + 1;
                fi;
            od;

            if p = p2+1 then
                res := res + 1;
            fi;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;

X := n -> coeftayl(1/(1-3*z+z^2), z = 0, n);
X2 := n -> fibonacci(2*n+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a string acceptable if it satisfies the constraints of the problem, and let the number of acceptable strings of length $n$ be $a_n$.  All acceptable strings are either happy or unhappy.  A string is happy if the last 2 in the string is followed by at least one 0; otherwise it is unhappy.  Let $h_n$ be the number of happy strings of length $n$ and $u_n$ be the number of unhappy strings, so 
$$a_n = h_n + u_n$$
  A happy string of length $n$ consists of either a happy string of length $n-1$ followed by a 0 or a 1, or an unhappy string of length $n-1$ followed by a 0.  So for $n > 1$,
$$h_n = 2h_{n-1} + u_{n-1}$$
An unhappy string of length $n$ consists of a happy string of length $n-1$ followed by a 2, or an unhappy string of length $n-1$ followed by a 1.  So for $n > 1$,
$$u_n = h_{n-1}+u_{n-1}$$
Together with $h_1 =2$ and $u_1= 1$, these recurrences allow us to compute as many values of $a_n$ as we like.

Comment: Could you interpret it to a recurrence relation for $a_n$, without h or u?